# Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a pom.xml file where I get this message Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found. I recently started using Maven and been looking around without any answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Declarations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My issue is with

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

maven-compiler-plugin says Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:' not found.

Comment: You don't have a version in the plugin. Try `<version>3.8.1</version>`.  Also, be consistent with your versions. You have `19` in the compiler plugin, but `1.8` for `maven.compiler.source` in the `properties`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the problem indeed

Comment: Use more recent version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.10.1) overview: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/